# How to stop timer on ATmega328

Tags: timer, arduino, avr

I wrote some simple code where I am using the timer1 on my Arduino Uno. The problem is I can't stop the timer any way I try.

I am using this program to count and show on the display the number of external interrupts on pin 2 while measuring the time. But when I press button `fin` I want to stop generating interrupts for the program which is increasing the variable time called `cas`. Can you help somehow, please?

My code:

```cpp
#include <OLED_I2C.h>
#define alarm_output 10 
#define fin 13

int suma=0;
int alarm=0;
float cas=0;

OLED  myOLED(SDA, SCL, 8);
extern uint8_t MediumNumbers[];
extern uint8_t BigNumbers[];
extern uint8_t SmallFont[];

void setup(void) {

   pinMode(alarm_output,OUTPUT);
   digitalWrite(alarm_output,LOW);
   pinMode(fin,INPUT_PULLUP);
   pinMode(9,INPUT_PULLUP);

   //interrupt
   interrupts(); 
   attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(2), displej, CHANGE);

   //first screen
   myOLED.begin();
   myOLED.setFont(SmallFont);
   myOLED.print("TIME:", 0, 30);
   myOLED.print("INTERRUPT:", 0, 56);
   myOLED.print("Laser game", CENTER, 0);
   myOLED.setFont(MediumNumbers);
   myOLED.printNumF(cas,1,RIGHT,20);
   myOLED.setFont(BigNumbers);
   myOLED.printNumI(suma, RIGHT, 40);
   myOLED.update();

   //start loop
   up:;
   if(digitalRead(9)==1)
      goto up;

   // TIMER 1 for interrupt frequency 10 Hz:
   cli(); // stop interrupts
   TCCR1A = 0; // set entire TCCR1A register to 0
   TCCR1B = 0; // same for TCCR1B
   TCNT1  = 0; // initialize counter value to 0
   // set compare match register for 10 Hz increments
   OCR1A = 24999; // = 16000000 / (64 * 10) - 1 (must be <65536)
   // turn on CTC mode
   TCCR1B |= (1 << WGM12);
   // Set CS12, CS11 and CS10 bits for 64 prescaler
   TCCR1B |= (0 << CS12) | (1 << CS11) | (1 << CS10);
   // enable timer compare interrupt
   TIMSK1 |= (1 << OCIE1A);
   sei(); // allow interrupts
}

void displej(){
   suma++;
   alarm=3; 
}

ISR(TIMER1_COMPA_vect){
   cas=cas+0.1;
   if(alarm>0)
      alarm--;  

}

void loop(void) {
   myOLED.setFont(MediumNumbers);
   myOLED.printNumF(cas,1,RIGHT,20);
   myOLED.setFont(BigNumbers);
   myOLED.printNumI(suma, RIGHT, 40);
   myOLED.update();

   if(digitalRead(fin)==0){
      cli();
      TCCR1B |= (0 << CS12) | (0 << CS11) | (0 << CS10);  //this do now work
      detachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(2));
      sei();
   }
   if(alarm>0)
       digitalWrite(alarm_output,HIGH);
   else
       digitalWrite(alarm_output,LOW);

   delay(10);

}
```

Comment: What exactly did you want the line `TCCR1B |= (0 << CS12) | (0 << CS11) | (0 << CS10);` to do? The way it is written, the value of TCCR1B is unchanged.

Comment: The comment above is correct.  That statement will not change TCCR1B.  See my answer below for how to correctly reset the register and stop the timer.

Comment: For your use case, it would be totally OK and common to just leave the timer interrupt running and use an additional variable as flag to enable/disable the counting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've tested all three methods for "turning off the timer."  Just comment out the one you prefer in the code below to see it demonstrated.  All three are effective at getting the Arduino's LED to quit blinking.

```
void setup(void) {
   pinMode(13,OUTPUT);
   digitalWrite(13,LOW);
   interrupts(); 

   // TIMER 1 for interrupt frequency 10 Hz:
   cli(); // stop interrupts
   TCCR1A = 0; // set entire TCCR1A register to 0
   TCCR1B = 0; // same for TCCR1B
   TCNT1  = 0; // initialize counter value to 0
   // set compare match register for 10 Hz increments
   OCR1A = 24999; // 200 millisecond cycle
   // turn on CTC mode
   TCCR1B |= (1 << WGM12);
   // Set CS12, CS11 and CS10 bits for 64 prescaler
   TCCR1B |= (0 << CS12) | (1 << CS11) | (1 << CS10);
   // enable timer compare interrupt
   TIMSK1 |= (1 << OCIE1A);
   sei(); // allow interrupts
}

volatile uint8_t count = 0;
volatile uint8_t timer_flip = 0;


ISR(TIMER1_COMPA_vect){
   if (timer_flip == 0)
     timer_flip = 1;
   else
     timer_flip = 0;

   if (timer_flip == 1)
     digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
   else
     digitalWrite(13, LOW);

   count++;  
}

void loop(void)
{
  if (count > 100)  // runs for a few seconds
  {
    //cli();  // One way to disable the timer, and all interrupts

    //TCCR1B &= ~(1<< CS12);  // turn off the clock altogether
    //TCCR1B &= ~(1<< CS11);
    //TCCR1B &= ~(1<< CS10);

    //TIMSK1 &= ~(1 << OCIE1A); // turn off the timer interrupt
    }
  }
```

This exact code is running on an Uno right beside me now.  I've tested all three "turn off" mechanisms above and they all work.

To make a minimal, verifiable example I stripped out all the OLED stuff.  I changed pin 13 to an output and set it to blink the LED while it could (and when it stops the timers and/or interrupts are clearly disabled).

A couple of learning points:

- You should not use pin 13 for your "fin" button without additional circuitry -- see [this Arduino official reference](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/DigitalPins).
- You should declare as `volatile` any variable that is written to in your interrupt service routines.
- Your choice of which method to turn off the timer depends on your goal.  You just disable the timer interrupt, disable all interrupts, or simply turn the clock source off.  The choice is yours.

Comment: Actually making 'count' volatile is not enough since it is a multi-byte variable. The condition "if (count > 100)" can be interrupted in between the check and count could then change.

Comment: @Rev1.0 While technically correct, I invented this variable strictly for the demonstration.  It is monotonically increasing and the demonstration (of the various ways to turn off the timer) is over after it passes a value of 100.  In a real program I'd of course turn off interrupts while updating it but to help this OP, I just wanted something that would allow the demo to run for a few seconds then turn off by the mechanism of his choosing.  Thanks for pointing it out though.

Comment: Your code works, I thing i figure out where is the problem. I guess library `OLED_I2C.h` is using functions `sei()` and `cli()` in it. THANK YOU for your help and answers. By the way i saw useful comand for flipping the led like this:


`digitalWrite(13,digitalRead(13)^1)`

Comment: Thanks.  Feel free up upvote my second answer if it helped you, and it might help others later.  As to the `^1` expression, use that if you prefer.  I wanted to make my answer as clear and easy to read as possible, for you and for others who may follow.

Comment: Since you titled it "learning points" I thought I better point it out, because many people are not aware of this and think volatile in sufficient. Of course this is not directly relevant to the question anyway ;)

Comment: @Rev1.0 indeed, and for that reason I just changed to uint8_t.  Less confusion that way.  Thanks for pointing it out, I'm still pretty new to this.

Comment: Writing multiple times to the TCCR1B register is suboptimal, i.e. it's better to disable the clock like this: `TCCR1B &= ~ ((1 << CS12) | (1 << CS11) | (1 << CS10));`

Comment: @maxschlepzig Indeed, a single write to the register is better; I originally answered as I did make the separate operations more obvious, not necessarily to optimize.  But good edit, good suggestion, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Sure thing!  There are two ways you can do it.  You can simply stop the timer *interrupt* but leave the timer running using:

```
TIMSK1 &= ~(1 << OCIE1A);
```

Or, you can stop the timer *altogether* by altering the clock source to "none" like:

```
TCCR1B &= ~((1 << CS12) | (1 << CS11) | (1 << CS10));
```

which effectively undoes what you did to select the clock source in the first place.  After this the CS12-CS11-CS10 bits will be 0-0-0 and the clock source will be stopped.  See p. 134 of the datasheet.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I see my fault now. I have gaps in c langue. I thought comand "TCCR1B |= (0 << CS12)" set bit CS12 of register TCCR1B to zero. I did not realize this comands are not functions but logic operators.

Comment: Can i have another question, why function "cli()" does not stop timer, when it shoud stop all interrupts.

Comment: You are correct; `cli()` will stop all interrupts, including the timers.  That is a viable way so stop the timers, as long as your code is not dependent on other interrupts.

Comment: I am programming in arduiono IDE but cli() does nothing, even when i replace sei() with cli() in timer setup function, timer will start anyway.

Comment: @andz Is the code in your question still the code that you are actually runnning?

Comment: @andz  New completely verifiable answer below with all three methods coded -- simply uncomment the one you want to try.

Comment: Note that by disabling interrupts with cli(), the timer will keep running and the timer interrupt flag will still get set. Its just the execution of the ISR that is prevented.